# Mockito: returning the passed parameter

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a mock object:

```
HttpUriRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpUriRequest.class);
```

on which my code calls

```
request.setHeader(key, value);
```

How can the mock return the `value` when the `getFirstHeader()` method is called

```
request.getFirstHeader(key).getValue();
```

where the `key` and the expected return `value` are the parameters from the `setHeader` invocation ?

`request.getFirstHeader(key)` returns an object of type `Header` which has a method `getValue()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my own problem:

```
    final MutableWrapper<String> stringWrapper = new MutableWrapper<>();
    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            stringWrapper.wrap(invocation.getArgumentAt(1, String.class));
            return null;
        }
    }).when(request).setHeader(Matchers.eq(HEADER), Matchers.anyString());

    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Header>() {
        @Override
        public Header answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Header header = Mockito.mock(Header.class);
            Mockito.when(header.getValue()).thenReturn(stringWrapper.unwrap());
            return header;
        }
    }).when(request).getFirstHeader(Matchers.eq(HEADER));
    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you might want to 'spy' on a real object instead of mocking it.

```
HttpGet request = Mockito.spy(new HttpGet("/"));
request.setHeader(key, value);

Mockito.verify(request).getFirstHeader(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that i think is a good hint for you.

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

/**
 * Created by soroosh on 1/26/15.
 */
public class MockitoTest {
    @org.junit.Test
    public void ttt(){
        class  HttpUriRequest{
            public String getFirstHeader(){
                return "Header";
            }
        }
        HttpUriRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpUriRequest.class);
        Mockito.when(request.getFirstHeader()).thenReturn("yoohoo");
        System.out.println(request.getFirstHeader());

    }
}
```

Let me know if the code could not help you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not what I'm looking for.